# Pass a nested function as a parameter

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, purely-functional

Is there a way nest functions and pass them as a parameter?
I have this 2 functions:

```
function mayus(string) {
    return string.toUpperCase();
}

function removeA(string) {
    return string.replace(/A/g, "");
}
```

and I want to apply them in 2 different ways

```
function stringHandler1(stringID) {
    var newString = mayus(removeA(getString(stringID))); 
    return newString;
}

function stringHandler2(stringID) {
    var newString = removeA(mayus(getString(stringID)));
    return newString;
}
```

The 2 stringHandlers return slightly different strings, but they are fairly similar. Is there a way to use one string handler that takes 2 parameters (the stringID and the operation)

```
function stringHandlerINeed(string, operation) {
    var newString = operation(string);
    alert(newString);
}
```

I want to do something like

> stringHandlerINeed("516af2", mayus(removeA))

**Update:**
I marked jJ' as the answer because it doesn't require me to change any of the functions I already have, and it's the concept I was looking for, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23960262/1733169) by juvian is so simple makes me wish I had come up with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you really want is probably **function composition**... one way to implement it is like this:

```
function compose() {
    var fns = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return function (arg) {
        fns.forEach(function (fn) {
            arg = fn(arg);
        });
        return arg;
    };
}

compose(mayus, removeA)('axA'); // -> "X"
compose(removeA, mayus)('axA'); // -> "AX"
```

There are endless applications of this concept. You can use any number of functions chained in `compose`. You can name the composed function:

```
var mayusRemoveA = compose(mayus, removeA);
```

You can also create a constant function (something like your handler above) instead of values that are evaluated by calling composed function directly...

```
var theHandlerINeed = compose(function () { return 'axA'; }, mayus, removeA);

theHandlerINeed(); // -> "X"
```

Answer (score 4):

Best way I can think of is sending the functions in an array according to the order of the operations, and then evaluate each one at a time:

```
function stringHandlerINeed(string, operation) {
    var newString=string;
    for(var i =0; i< operation.length;i++){
        newString=operation[i](newString);
    }
    alert(newString);
}


stringHandlerINeed("516af2", [mayus,removeA]) // alerts 516F2
```

Answer (score 1):

I was going the same direction of juvian, but simpler.

In this jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/4J2AH/), I pass in the string and functions I want to operate on, then do those operations and return the new string.

The problem with `stringHandlerINeed("516af2", mayus(removeA))` is that when you call mayus(removeA), this means you are actually invoking the mayus function which is passing in another function. When it goes to upper case a function, javascript will throw an error.